# Using Redux-Persist with Baqend React/Redux Starter

Tags: react-redux, baqend

Does anyone know how to add redux-persist https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist
to the store from the starter kit: https://www.baqend.com/guide/starter-kits/react/

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { createStoreWithBaqend, baqendReducer } from 'redux-baqend'
import middlewares from '../middleware'
import reducers from '../reducers'

import { db } from 'baqend'

export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const reducer = combineReducers({
    baqend: baqendReducer,
    ...reducers
  })
  const middleware = applyMiddleware(
    ...middlewares
  )
  return createStoreWithBaqend(
    db.connect('remarkable-apple-XX', true),
    reducer,
    initialState,
    middleware
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but the documentation from redux-persist looks like you just add the autoRehydrate and wrap the created store in the persistStore method. The createStoreWithBaqend method is basically the same like the normal createStore method, but adds some baqend specific stuff to your store.

I would try it like this:

```
export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const reducer = combineReducers({
    baqend: baqendReducer,
    ...reducers
  })
  const middleware = applyMiddleware(
    ...middlewares
  )
  const store = createStoreWithBaqend(
    db.connect('remarkable-apple-XX', true),
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      middleware,
      autoRehydrate()
    )
  )
  return persistStore(store)
}
```

Remember to import compose from the redux library. Hope this helps.